# How to i send NFTs in bulk on the polygon network

Tags: nft, gnosis-safe

is it possible to send NFT in bulk to another wallet using gnosis safe?

were struggling to figure out a way to do this, much help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create "BATCHES" of transactions.
Nevertheless, keep in mind you cannot have infinite transactions because there is a GAS LIMIT per block on all EVM chains.

Example:

- Send 10-20 tx in one batch **is acceptable**
- Send 10000 tx in one batch **will result in tx failure**

In order to use Gnosis Safe, you will need to familiarize yourself with the transaction builder here https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4680071-transaction-builder

You will need the following:

- contract address of the NFT collection you want to send
- ABI of the NFT collection (in raw format)
- know the NFT ids that are in your wallet so you can send them (e.g ID 1, ID 4, ID 5)

You will then create a bulk transaction and paste the contract address
[image]

Then select the method "transfer"
[image]

and finally pass the _to address (the receiver) and instead of value, the NFT id.
[image]

Once your batch is created, create and execute
[image]